# How to print Strings to an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to simply have these names printed to an output label when a "Print" button is clicked. Right Now when I click the button to print the names it pops up 3 lines that say `System.String[].` How do i get these names to print and not the `System.String[]` message? Thanks!

```
string[] names = new string[] {"Kevin", "Anthony", "Mike", "Allan" };
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //taverse the array and dispalay the scores into the label
    string output = "";
    for(int i=0;i<=names.Length; i++)
    {
        output = output + names + "\n";
    }
    displayLabel.Text = output;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.Join()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) will combine string elements from an array into a new, single string with dividing characters.

```
string.Join("\n", names);
```

Answer (score 4):

you forgot to add index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++){
    output = output + names[i] + "\n";
}
```

Comment: You could also use += operator ```output += names[i] + "\n"```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
for (int i = 0; i <= names.Length-1; i++){
    output = output + names[i] + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use just these three lines of code:

```
            var names = new string[] { "Kevin", "Anthony", "Mike", "Allan" };
            var output = names.Aggregate("", (current, name) => current + (name + Environment.NewLine));
            displayLabel.Text = output;
```